# Removing part of string in a python set

Tags: python, string, set

#### What is the pythonic way to remove all the parts of string upto and including dot from a set

```
theSet={'products.add_product','products.add_category','books.view_books','cats.change_cats'} 

#desired output
newSet = {'add_product','add_category','view_books', 'change_cats'}
```

Comment: I suggest scanning throuh the documentation for `str` to find any helpful methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try `string.split`

```py
{i.split('.')[-1] for i in theSet}
```

```
{'add_category', 'add_product', 'change_cats', 'view_books'}
```

**NOTE**: The order does not matter since it is `set`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`str.index()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/index)

```
data = {'products.add_product', 'products.add_category',
        'books.view_books', 'cats.change_cats'}
result = {word[word.index(".") + 1:] for word in data}

print(result)
```

Gives : output order may vary because a set is an unordered collection of items.

```
{'view_books', 'change_cats', 'add_category', 'add_product'}
```